# Find all IPs attached to server

Tags: unix, ip, centos

I've bought a dedicated server and they gave me 5 public IPs.
But I don't know how to get all IPs that attached to my server by using unix command.
Please help me out.
My server is running with CentOS 64bit.
Thank you!

Comment: If the addresses are sequential you can discern the ip addresses from the network and netmask numbers.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. You want to find out which IP addresses belong to your server? Or configure your server to respond to the IPs reserved by your ISP for your use?

Comment: yes, I want to find out which IP belong to my server.

Answer (score 1):

see the man pages of the  `ip` or `ifconfig` command,